# Scipy.integrate gives odd results

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am still struggling with scipy.integrate.quad.

Sparing all the details, I have an integral to evaluate.  The function is of the form of the integral of a product of functions in x, like so:

```
Z(k) = f(x) g(k/x) / abs(x)
```

I know for certain the range of integration is between tow positive numbers.  Oddly, when I pick a wide range that I know must contain all values of x that are positive - like integrating from 1 to 10,000,000 - it intgrates fast and gives an answer which looks right.  But when I fingure out the exact limits - which I know sice f(x) is zero over a lot of the real line - and use those, I get another answer that is different.  They aren't very different, though I know the second is more accurate.

After much fiddling I got it to work OK, but then needed to add in an exopnentiation - I was at least getting a 'smooth' answer for the computed function of z.  I had this working in an OK way before I added in the exponentiation (which is needed), but now the function that gets generated (z) becomes more and more oscillatory and peculiar.

Any idea what is happening here?  I know this code comes from an old Fortran library, so there must be some known issues, but I can't find references.

Here is the core code:

```
def normal(x, mu, sigma) :
    return (1.0/((2.0*3.14159*sigma**2)**0.5)*exp(-(x-
                                      mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)))

def integrand(x, z, mu, sigma, f) : 
return np.exp(normal(z/x, mu, sigma)) * getP(x, f._x, f._y) / abs(x)




    for _z in range (int(z_min), int(z_max) + 1, 1000):
        z.append(_z)
        pResult = quad(integrand, lb, ub,
                       args=(float(_z), MU-SIGMA**2/2, SIGMA, X),
                       points = [100000.0],
                       epsabs = 1, epsrel = .01)    # drop error estimate of tuple 
        p.append(pResult[0])   # drop error estimate of tuple
```

By the way, getP() returns a linearly interpolated, piecewise continuous,but non-smooth function to give the integrator values that smoothly fit between the discrete 'buckets' of the histogram.

Comment: A [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it easier to help you.  In general, though, the more you know about your integrand, the more hints you can give to `quad` to get an accurate result efficiently.  How smooth is the integrand?  Does it have discontinuities?  Is its derivative continuous?  Have you plotted it to understand its behavior?

Comment: I will post some code.  It is an algorithm to compute the product of random variables.  So, one of the functions is a normal distribution, which is the k/x term.  The other is a piecewise approximation to an arbitrary distribution based on empirical data, so it is really a 'histogram'.  I could see that causing problems, so the term f(x) is actually an linearly interpolated value that maintains continuity but obviously is not differentiable, itself, at the the boundaries of 'buckets'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many numerical methods, it can be very sensitive to asymptotes, zeros, etc.  The only choice is to keep giving it 'hints' if it will accept them.

Comment: What hints did you end up giving that solved your problem. This answer isn't very useful in its current state. It's essentially saying "be careful'.